# Can't build kudan ios unity3d project with duplicate symbol only using -ObjC

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, kudan

We got the following linking error trying to build against unity3d version 5.3.5p4

It occurs when using Other Linker Flgs -ObjC. But we cannot remove -Objc (other libraries use)

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARAPIKey in:
/xcode/Libraries/KudanAR/Plugins/iOS/libKudanPlugin.a(ARAPIKey.o)
/xcode/Libraries/KudanAR/Plugins/iOS/libKudanPlugin.a(libKudanCV++.a-arm64-master.o)
...(duplicate errors)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Kudan does not currently support usage of the -ObjC flag with the framework. The only thing I can suggest is trying to use -force_load  and get the library to link that way.

Comment: other libraries can use -force_load. I'm trying it.